# I'm trying to make a Magic the Gathering app, how should I go about storing the card attributes?

Tags: python, oop

I'm working on my first non-school-related project and I'm a little bit stumped on how I should go about handling something. The project is in Python, but I guess the question itself is more conceptual/OOP-based. The goal of the project is to create an application that takes input for a 40 card MtG deck and displays some probability figures based on the contents of the deck. Using Scryfall's API I have a made a text document that contains the card information for a set of magic cards. The text document is actually just a bunch of lines with each line containing a JSON format dictionary and I have all the information I need in the text file. It looks something like this:

```
{ 'name' : 'card_1_name', 'attribute1' : ' card_1_attribute1', 'attribute2' : 'card_1_attribute2', 'etc' : 'etc'}
{ 'name' : 'card_2_name', 'attribute1' : ' card_2_attribute1', 'attribute2' : 'card_2_attribute2', 'etc' : 'etc'}
{ 'name' : 'card_3_name', 'attribute1' : ' card_3_attribute1', 'attribute2' : 'card_3_attribute2', 'etc' : 'etc'}
```

For those familiar with MtG, think:

```
{'name' : 'lightning bolt', 'color' : 'red', 'type' : 'instant', ...., 'etc' : 'etc'}
```

It goes on for about 250 different cards. I can read the document to get any information about any card I want, though because the formatting is weird I have to use a for-loop that reads each line individually and converts it to an actual python dictionary using ast.literal_eval to identify the line that contains the dictionary with the 'name' of the card I want.

Here's what I'm currently trying to do. I figured I could create a class 'card' that has the attributes that every magic card has, like a name and a color. I want to then make subclasses of the 'card' class that contain other attributes that are specific to certain card types, for example a card type in MtG is 'creature'. Only creatures have the 'power' attribute and the 'toughness' attribute. So the class 'creature' would inherit the basic attributes from 'card' and also have its own special attributes.

My line of thinking is that a deck of cards should be a list of card objects. My problem is I am having a hard time automating the process of making the card objects. This is the 'card' class I have currently:

```
class magic_card:

    def __init__(self, card_dict): # card_dict is the dictionary that contains the card data

        self.name = card_dict['name']
        self.cmc = card_dict['cmc']
        self.colors = card_dict['colors']
        self.rarity = card_dict['rarity']
```

How can I automate the process of creating these ~250 card objects so that the 'card''s name is the name of the card instance? What i mean is I want to be able to make a loop that does this:

```
f = open("document_that_holds_card_information.txt", "r")

for i in range(1, 251):
    card_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(f.readline())
    card_name = (card_dictionary['name'])
    card_name = magic_card(card_dictionary) # I want this magic_card instance's name to be the value stored in card_dictionary['name'] 

f.close()
```

Is this doable? Or am I overthinking things? My other thought is I could just reformat my text document so that it is easier to search through by formatting it to look like

```
['card_name1' : {#dictionary contents}, 'card_name2' : {#dictionary contents}, 'card_name3' : {#dictionary contents}....]
```

I'm really struggling with this and I feel like I might be tunnel visioning on a bad approach. Please help!

Edit: Alright the consensus seems to be that I am overthinking it. I've decided to reformat the file containing my card data to be in the proper JSON format instead of having multiple lines of JSON. Instead of having a deck of cards be a list of card objects, a deck of cards will be a list of card dictionaries

Comment: You could use a database and store the card data inside of it instead of text files which I thihnk would be better, but it's up to you.

Comment: If it is supposed to be a standalone app that other folks can run on their machines, then take a look at sqlite database.  If you're hosting this as a web application, then you'll want some sort of database like mariadb or postgresql or any of the proprietary variants.

Comment: You have several options. Database, XML file, json file, config file, etc... Use whatever is the most clear and simple for you, don't over engineer. Also, your approach is sensible, reading data from a file to create objects is common.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: This chapter from game programming patterns may help you: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/prototype.html

Comment: You say the data is JSON... obviously the whole file isn't valid JSON if it contains multiple top-level objects, but if each line individually is actually JSON, it would be better to use `json.loads()` than `ast.literal_eval()`. (Of course, if the strings are single-quoted like your example, then they aren't JSON after all...)

Comment: Is there something more here than unpacking a dictionary into keyword arguments with `f(**arg_dict)`?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're wanting to do but rather than having your own local database why not use the MTG SDK - https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-python - I personally have used it a lot and it provides a lot of functionality... If you are wanting a database of MTG cards this is the way to go - you could pull the data into your Class very simply.... If this is what you want - ask - and I'll give an answer using it :)